# What does "In each generation, 25% of offspring resulted from mutation without crossover" mean in the context of NEAT?

Tags: papers, neat, crossover-operators, mutation-operators, genetic-operators

I am reading through the [NEAT paper](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf). In parameter settings, page 15, there is:

> In each generation, 25% of offspring resulted from mutation without crossover.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In genetic algorithms, mutation without crossover simply means that part of the population is randomly changed. In this case this is applied to 25% of the population.

The remaining 75% either remain unchanged (generally the best performing specimen), or will be combined with other specimen (using crossover). It's a bit more complex here, as the genome is connecting weights in networks, and they use 'species', where certain individuals are treated as separate groups from the rest of the population.